# Selecting Semicolons Within SQL Script but Excluding Semicolon at End of Line

Tags: regex, notepad++

```sql
INSERT INTO database 
VALUES (1000008,"JONES, Beverley","GEN-BAB-001-02","L","93;104;185;245","Babcock, John U.E.");
```

A non-profit maintains a database of sources of historical information. I would like to REPLACE the `;` in the section `93;104;185;245` while leaving the final `;` in place to complete the record.

I have been going line by line converting the syntax manually in MySQL Workbench but it occurred to me that a FIND and REPLACE in Notepad++ would be "much faster", since the database has over 1.4 million lines of code. My fleeting appreciation of REGEX suggests that a solution does exist.

So far, all changes have been manual.

Comment: What are you replacing the `;` character with? Quick fix would be to actually perform a full search and replace of the character `;` with say `@`. After the full search and replace has been performed, you need to perform another full search and replace, this time for the character set`)@` (this denotes the ending of your script's each line) with `);`. Just tried and tested with Notepad++ after copying your sample script 200x.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\));`
- Replace with: `.` You can change for the character you want.
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\))     # negative lookbehind, make we haven't a closing parenthesis before
;           # semicolon
```

**Result for given example:**

```
INSERT INTO database 
VALUES (1000008,"JONES, Beverley","GEN-BAB-001-02","L","93.104.185.245","Babcock, John U.E.");
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Works great! This database was created over twenty years by numerous inexperienced volunteers. Some of the lines have blanks, usually one, two or three between the numbers rather than ;. What modification would allow a separator to be inserted between the numbers instead of the blanks?

Comment: @Bernie: Have a try with this in “find what:“ `(?<!\))[;\s]+` and anything you want in “replace with:”.

Comment: Thanks Toto. This second expression finds all blanks in all lines, not just those between the target numerals. The first expression targets the correct area and would be ideal if it could pinpoint blanks between numerals with the option to insert, say # or ;.

Comment: @Bernie: How about Find: `(?<=\d)[;\h]+(?=\d)` Replace: `.`

Comment: This one looks good, Toto! For a beginner in REGEX what resources would you recommend?

Comment: A good site: https://www.regular-expressions.info/ ; more advanced, a book: http://freecomputerbooks.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: @Bernie: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)